# Hide Discount Item Type on Netsuite PDF/HTML Advanced

Tags: javascript, java, netsuite

'm trying to modify my Advanced HTML/PDF template so that it hides all Discount Item (Item lines) on invoices. I found `SuiteAnswers` 33495 and the following code snippet `<#if !item.item?contains("Bed")>`, but unable to get it to work with `itemtype` (tried to modify it to `if !item.itemtype != 'discountitem'>`). Can someone help me?

Snippet from SuiteAnswer:

```
...
</#if>
<#if !item.item?contains("Bed")>
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="3" line-height="150%">${item.quantity}</td>
<td colspan="12"><span class="itemname"> ${item.item}</span><br 
/>${item.description}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount} </td>
</tr>
</#if>
</#list> 
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this condition: <#if item.itemtype != 'Discount'>
When figuring out the correct filter based on a field value, try printing that value to see what NetSuite is returning.

Comment: I try this one too and that didn't happen. What happens, it this, or all items disappeared or he shows all items.

Comment: Print item.itemtype on the PDF - what do you get for discount items? That will tell you what your condition should be.